# Nouveau doesn't recognize my chipset (136000a1)

Tags: 16.04, graphics, 64-bit, nouveau, nvidia-geforce

When I try to boot into a Live USB with 16.04.2 LTS, I get the following error:

> [3.358556] core perfctr but no constraints: unknown hardware!
>
> [4.154821] nouveau 0000:09:00.0: unknown chipset (136000a1)
>
> [6.107481] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
>
> [6.108023] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through

My monitor displays "Format not supported" and turns off. I can get a TTY prompt, but I'm not able to install an Nvidia graphics driver because /dev/loop0 is write-only.

"nomodeset rdblacklist=nouveau" does nothing as I don't have integrated graphics to fall back to.

My graphics card is a relatively new GTX 1060, and my CPU is a Ryzen.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a workaround.

I had to install the Ubuntu 16.04 Server image (which can be installed through TTY, no desktop needed),

- disable Nouveau through the known methods,
- download and install Nvidia-375 through the graphics-drivers PPA,
- make sure Nouveau is permanently disabled,
- then install lightdm and ubuntu-desktop.

It's a pretty typical Ubuntu setup now.